# Why do these 2 regular expressions not behave the same?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to create a regular expression with the constructor syntax like this `new RegExp('\bword\b', 'g')`, but it does not behave as expected. Rather it seems to create a regular expression that looks like this `/\bwor\b/g` with a missing last letter.

I have to use the constructor syntax to create the regular expression as I am dynamically creating the from a json file, and you can't put regex in json. So my question's are:

a. Why do these behave differently? and b. What can I do to remedy the situation?

Note: What I am attempting to do is create a regular expression that matches a whole word only and not a word that exists within another word.

Comment: you need two backslash on RegExp

Answer (score 14):

For a string `\b` means *backspace*.

For a regex `\b` means *word-boundary*.

To make sure the regex version is used, add an extra backslash `\` before each backslash in the string to escape the escape characters.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize they had different syntaxes

Comment: @mascaliente don't treat them as "different syntaxes". It's just a requirement for string literals, that slashes should be escaped.