# RegExp Object Literal notation vs Constructor notation difference

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var digits = "B2";
var re = new RegExp("/\d+/");
console.log(/\d+/.test(digits));
console.log("digits matches to :", digits.match(re));
```

why does digits.match(re) return NULL whereas the .test returns true?
When I just run digits.match("/\d+/"); I get the correct answer.

Comment: I'm getting `null` for `digits.match("/\d+/")` as well. Are you sure that's the code you used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new RegExp()` syntax doesn't use forward slashes `/` as the delimiter. It's assumed that the entire string is the regex. Also, backslashes must be escaped, since this is a requirement of strings when you aren't referencing an escape character.

These are the same:

```
digits.match(new RegExp("\\d+")); // 2

digits.match(/\d+/); // 2
```

Comment: I'd like to stress that the backslash escaping is really important, because bugs can creep in at unexpected times such as [this hard-to-spot time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37516746/5743988) with `\b`.