# Javascript regex keeps returning false

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a problem with regex in Javascript. 
I need to retrieve an IP address from a String. 
I tested my regex with regex101.com and everything works fine.

Here's my regex :

```
var regex = new RegExp('(\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b:[0-9]+)|(localhost:[0-9]+)', 'i');
```

And here's the snippet I have

```
console.log(regex.test('127.0.0.1:8080/test'));
```

Result is always false.

I tried several methods, string.match, the regex package v0.1.1 also.

Is there something I am missing ?

Thank you.

Comment: Which portion of string are you trying to match?

Comment: Another possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37516721/5743988

Comment: I want to find an IP address from the start of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is just that you haven't escaped your backslashes.

```
var regex = new RegExp('(\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b:[0-9]+)|(localhost:[0-9]+)', 'i');

console.log(regex.test('127.0.0.1:8080/test'));
> true
```

The fundamental problem here is that the backslash has special meaning as an escape character, both to JavaScript *and* to RegExp.

So, when JavaScript sees your `'\b'`, it interprets it as an escape character - in this case a backspace character. This interpretation happens *before* it gets to the RegExp engine.

So, you need to escape your backslashes by doubling them.

Comment: Yes, this is it, thanks so much !